# Detect minimization of remote desktop connection window

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop

Is there anyway to detect if a remote desktop connection window has been minimized on a certain computer. The use case is as below:
We have students who will be taking exams on a virtual machine, by connecting to the VM through a remote desktop connection application. This is to make sure the student is in a controlled environment for the exam, and the VM will have its own firewall rules etc to combat cheating and collaboration between students.

But if the student minimizes the remote desktop application on his computer and accesses the web through his own physical machine(and not the VM) to chat with other students, this will beat the purpose.

Hence it would be great if I could detect this minimization of the remote desktop application. Having to install a software for this on the student's physical machine would not be ideal. I want to know if there is anyway I can detect this from the VM.

Comment: Isn't this defeated by anyone with two monitors (or two PCs)?

Comment: So over here we're assuming there is going to be just 1 PC belonging to the student.